# Disable onItemClickListener for one adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

I've two list one with custom adapter and other with array adapter. So i want `onItemClickListener` to work with custom adapter listview and it will automatically disable when I start using same listview for array adapter. To initiate array adapter list I'm using button. And using same listview for both adapters.

I've already try using `ListView.setClickable(false)`
. but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

see you have to play with you `onItemClickListener` like as

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {      
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
 }
```

here you can set a `Boolean flag` whether you are accessing you list with `custom adapter` or from `array adapter`. and on the base of this flag you can you this listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use `view.setEnabled(false);` for  `convertView` in Adapter

Try something like that :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, null);

         //  if you want to disable list view then
        view.setEnabled(false);
        // otherwise you can call 
        view.setEnabled(true);

    }       

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Hello");

    return view;
}
```